# Solving this cubic equation $x^3+15x^2+24x-40=0$ algebraically

Tags: algebra-precalculus, cubics

I have :  $x^3+15x^2+24x-40=0$

When I use $x=u-a/3$ where $a=15$ and I replace it gives :

$u^3-51u+90=0$

Now, my discriminant is inferior to $0$...

How do I find out at least one solution of this cubic equation without using trigonometric methods? I only learned how to solve cubics with algebraical methods...

Thank you!

Comment: After being here for more than a year, it is time to [learn](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) how to write math here...

Comment: Hint: Try setting $ x = 1$.

Comment: To expand on A.P.'s comment.  In this case all you'd have to do @Astroman is add `$` before and after each equation and change the `a/3` in line two to `{a \over 3}`.

Comment: Ok, I understand I need to learn to write math, just have to stop procrastinating ...

Comment: Hi Astroman, non matter you discriminant is negative (in which case the root are real) you can always solve your equation following the Cardano way you wanted to use but going through a non real  road (no matter if you have a clear 1 as a root).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $x=1$ is an easily obtainable root of your cubic equation. As Clement points out in the comment, the first root is usually easily obtainable. You can see the constant term of your cubic, it is $-40$, so the product of your roots is $40$. So you can try some simple factors of $40$ like $1,-1,2$ etc.

Factoring it out yields
$$(x-1)(x^2+16x+40)=0$$

Solving the quadratic, you get the other two roots.

Comment: The x=1 was just found by luck ???

Comment: As a general guideline, it's always a good idea to try and eyeball the "simple roots" first: 1,-1, 2...

Comment: Yes, I think that's what I wanted then. Thank you!

Comment: @Astroman I've slightly edited my answer.

Comment: Even if you don't want to eyeball it, you can do the Rational Roots Test  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Answer (score 0):

When in a cubic equation coefficient of the highest power of the variable(here the variable is x)is1 then try out the different factors of the constant term of the equation.So try out the factors of 40 which are 1,2,4,5,8,10,20,40 in both signs that is positive as well as negative factors.By trying+1 you get 1 as a solution.Then divide the equation by x-1.Then you get a quotient which is qudratic which you can solve easily.This method is similar to factor theorem.